# Why is the lineskip different when setting the font size in a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize

I want to change the font size of text in a node. Ideally finally I have multiple font sizes in a node. However when trying to change the font size in the node, I get unexpected different line spacings. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=north east,text width=0.2\textwidth,font=\small] at (0,0) {This text demonstrates how your own text will look when you replace the placeholder with your own text.};
\node[anchor=north west,text width=0.2\textwidth] at (0,0) {\small This text demonstrates how your own text will look when you replace the placeholder with your own text.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can clearly see, setting the font size in the node leads to a different line spacing. How can I prevent this? And what is going on there?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very likely, the text for the node is enclosed in a group and the final `\par` that triggers line breaking is outside this group, so the standard baseline distance is in effect and not the one pertaining to `\small`.

You can see the same effect below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
\raggedright
\small
This text demonstrates how your own text will 
look when you replace the placeholder with 
your own text.
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
\raggedright
{\small
This text demonstrates how your own text will 
look when you replace the placeholder with 
your own text.}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Add `\par`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=north east,text width=0.2\textwidth,font=\small] at (0,0) {This text demonstrates 
how your own text will look when you replace the placeholder with your own text.};
\node[anchor=north west,text width=0.2\textwidth] at (0,0) {\small This text demonstrates how 
your own text will look when you replace the placeholder with your own text.\par};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@egreg Not an answer, but an observation. If you overlap the two nodes you can see that even the space between the words look a little different, but the two nodes seem to have exactly the same dimensions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=north east,text width=0.2\textwidth,font=\small,draw] at (0,0) {This text demonstrates how your own text will look when you replace the placeholder with your own text.};
\node[anchor=north east,text width=0.2\textwidth,red,opacity=0.5,draw] at (0,0) {\small This text demonstrates how your own text will look when you replace the placeholder with your own text.\par};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: TikZ installs `\leftskip`s and `\rightskip`s that are dependent on the unit `em` right after it executes whatever was setup via the `font` key. When you use `\small` inside the node this don't get updated – similar to the baseline.